# ASP.NET AJAX, WebSeal Junctions, and Sessions

Tags: asp.net, ajax, cookies, junction, webseal

I've run up across a problem with ASP.NET AJAX (hooked up to WebServices directly) and accessing our site through a WebSeal junction.

Listing 11. On this page; http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/tivoli/library/t-ajaxtam/index.html explains that requests to pages which do not result in a content type of text/html are not sent with cookie data. Hence, no session. ASP.NET AJAX requests are returned with a content type of "application/json; charset=utf-8". As such, the WebSeal junction is not appending the Session Cookie to the request. This results in our WebService seeing the user as invalid, due to no session information.

The Junction has been setup properly with the -J parameter (thats an uppercase J, which appends the required script for WebSeal to the bottom of the page - this prevents forcing IE into quirks mode.) and we've confirmed that the necessary script exists in the output source.

I'm up for any suggestions at this point, as I'm out of ideas. FWIW, the site runs perfectly when not accessed through the WebSeal Junction.

Answer (score 0):

For what it is worth, I was seeing a similar issue with an AJAX app being accessed through WebSeal. What worked for me was to deploy the application with debugging turned off in the config file.

```
<compilation debug="false" ...>
```

With debugging turned on, there were some AJAX calls that would work fine when I accessed the site directly but would fail when access through WebSeal. Once I turned the debugging off, everything work fine.

YMMV